# How to make Foundation Zurb 4 non responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm a big fan of Foundation Zurb and lately I have made a couple of websites using Foundation 4. Everything was going well until one of my clients decided he actually wanted his website non responsive for this and that reason. I promptly told him I could easily make it however it turns out that something I thought would be easy peasy actually it's not, for me at least. So I hope someone could point me to the right way in order to get this issue solved.
Thank you so much!

Comment: You'll probably want to look in the CSS file for the @media declaration and then comment out the display sizes you don't want it to respond for.  http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html

Comment: I see so basically I must delete all the @media queries right?

Comment: Well, I'd comment them out first and test it.

Comment: that's an odd request!